# How to replace the characters of a variable with some random numbers in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to pick up a variable from Debug Sampler and replace the characters of the variables with some Randomly generated number. I have added a BeanShell Sampler for writing the custom code. Below is the piece of code:

> ```
> String myvariable = vars.get("Corr_ContextN");
> chars1 = new ArrayList();
> chars2 = new ArrayList();
>
> for(int i =0; i<myvariable.length(); i++) {
> chars1.add(myvariable.charAt(i)); }
>
> String value = chars1.toString();
>
> Random randomnumber = new Random();
> for (int idx=1; idx < 15; ++idx) {
> chars2.add(randomnumber.nextInt(100)); }
>
> String Newvalue1 = chars2.toString();
> vars.put("NewVariable", Newvalue1 );
> ```

By the above way I get a New variable in the Debug Sampler (NewVariable) with a list of random numbers. But I want to replace the existing variable "Corr_ContextN" with this NewVariable created. In other words the existing variable should be replaced by some dynamically generated number/variable.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the last line to be:

```
vars.put("Corr_ContextN", Newvalue1 );
```

---

P.S. Consider using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead of Beanshell. You can even reuse the same code which will perform much better being compiled by Groovy engine.

---

P.P.S. Be informed that **much easier** would be using [__Random function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) which is capable of storing randomly generated numbers into JMeter Variables as well as returning them in place where the function is called. Check out [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series to learn about functions in JMeter.

Comment: Thanks. Here the Variable Corr_ContextN gets replaced by Random numbers, however the number of characters in the variable is fixed to 14, since I am running the loop 14 times. But I want to display the exact number of random numbers as many characters the variable Corr_ContextN has in the beginning.